# Find date and value of a column maximum using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to find dates when `wipro close price` was `max` per `year`. *(What date and what price?)* Here's an example of some code I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nsepy import get_history
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.today()
wipro=get_history(symbol='WIPRO', start = start, end = end)
wipro.index = pd.to_datetime(wipro.index)

# This should get me my grouped results
wipro_agg = wipro.groupby(wipro.index.year).Close.idxmax()
```

Comment: Please post your code, so we can duplicate and help. :)

Comment: Format your code properly. And this code doesn't print anything or do you execute it line by line in a Python shell?

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem requires 2 steps. First, get the max price each year. Then, find the exact date of that instance.

```
# Find max price each year:
# note: specific format to keep as a dataframe
wipro_max_yr = wipro.groupby(wipro.index.dt.year)[['Close']].max()

# Now, do an inner join to find exact dates
wipro_max_dates = wipro_max_yr.merge(wipro, how='inner')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call "max" the same way you called "idxmax"

```
In [25]: df_ids = pd.DataFrame(wipro.groupby(wipro.index.year).Close.idxmax())
In [26]: df_ids['price'] = wipro.groupby(wipro.index.year).Close.max()
In [27]: df_ids.rename({'Close': 'date'}, axis= 1).set_index('date')
Out[27]: 
             price
date
2015-03-03  672.45
2016-04-20  601.25
2017-06-06  560.55
2018-12-19  340.70
2019-02-26  387.65
```